# Undo/redo Plugin in jquery

Tags: undo-redo

Is there any undo/redo plugin in jquery. If not how one can implement and undo/redo mechanism on a particular html emlement.

thanks.

Comment: Are you using a WYSIWYG editor component that needs undoing? Or do you want to undo things you do to HTML elements programmatically?

Comment: I m working on a design tool, where user can add text, background images and can edit those text/image, and in any particular time they can undo there work. I m using jquery as a development tool, i have googled for jquery undo plugin but could not find any suitable plugin which can perform undo operation ony any particular element.
Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [Undo](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Undo) plugin or even the [Undoable](http://mlntn.com/demos/jquery-undoable/) plugin.

Comment: I have already checked those links, the one on http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Undo merely provide any download link for the plugin. and the other one is not working in Mozila.

Answer (score 2):

My Undo Manager might fit your needs: https://github.com/ArthurClemens/Javascript-Undo-Manager

It is library agnostic, and quite easy to make it work with jQuery (see the demo).