# jQuery Undo/Redo

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I designed a web form that is used to design reports. Via this form I can add text, images, and I can also modify the properties of said elements such as the `border`, `font-size`, etc. Next I would like to add *undo* and *redo* functionality.

For example, if I add a border on an image, I'd like to make this *undoable*, as well if I modify the font-size of some text, I would like this too to be *undoable* and *redoable*. Using jQuery, how might I accomplish something like this?

I found this question [Undo/redo Plugin in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979863/undo-redo-plugin-in-jquery).

Comment: So you found a question that seems close to yours with a plugin answer. What have you tried?

Comment: would help a lot if you shared some of your code. In reality, creating such an app it is almost best to start with your undo system in place first in order to create the change of elements code to fit the undo system

Comment: are you still looking for help with this? I have been playing with something that might help but would need to understand your UI a bit better